# jQuery addClass() removeClass() methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with jQuery methods .addClass() .removeClass

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HEM7Q/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".button").click(function(e) {
  $(".position1").animate({left:"400px"},2000, function(e){
     $(".position1").addClass("position2").removeClass("position1");
     })
  });
});
```

see, initially the css.left is 20 px (because its defined in the class .position1). now, I animate the div till its left become 400px. After the animation is completed, I addClass position2 (where left is 50px) and I removeClass position1.

so shouldn't the div come back to left == 50 px after the completion of the animation?
why is it not happening, and what is the right code for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll say that the `animate` method is amending inline styles to get the desired effect which remain present even when the animation is completed (unless you actively revert) and this takes precedence over your defined style classes.

Answer (score 0):

Because inline styling has higher priority than external styles. You may want to change your `left` property in `.position2` to `left: 10px !imporant` to enforce using the property value.

http://jsfiddle.net/HEM7Q/6/

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove inline `left` from the styles,as inline styles take precedence over CSS classes:

```
$(".position1").animate({left:"400px"},2000, function(e){
    $(".position1").css("left","");  //Removing 'left' which was added by animation

    $(".position1").addClass("position2").removeClass("position1");
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HEM7Q/9/)